# Converting Java 2D array into an Objective-C 2D array

Tags: java, objective-c, arrays

I have this Java variable in my Table.java file:

```
int[][] evaluationTable = {{3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3},
{4, 6, 8, 10, 8, 6, 4},
{5, 8, 11, 13, 11, 8, 5},
{5, 8, 11, 13, 11, 8, 5},
{4, 6, 8, 10, 8, 6, 4},
{3, 4, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3}};
```

That I want to convert to **Objective-C** in my Table.m file. 
It's important that I steer clear away from NSArray, **NSMutableArray**, etc...

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Sampada I have tried creating a method that takes in 2d array and initializing it in an init method.

Comment: Please don't repost.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is a superset of C, for your literal array you can just use a C array. In C the array brackets come *after* the array name, and you must specify the number of columns - specifying the numbers of rows is optional; otherwise the declaration is the same as Java. So just change your code to:

```
int evaluationTable[][7] = { ...
```

or

```
int evaluationTable[6][7] = { ...
```

For more details look up *C arrays* and *compound literals*.

HTH